# How to change the refresh rate of location in KWGT

Tags: widget

I have designed a widget to display the current time, weather, and location. However, I noticed that KWGT keeps asking for location cause there are always green dots on my notification channel, and I also worry that it may use too much battery. Does anyone know how to change the refreshing rate?